# QTableView unexpectedly shifts left after inserting row to data using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pyqt, qtableview

----How The Problem Looks Like----

[image]

after I clicked on the ***Record button***, it becomes this

[image]

As you can see, the table just shifted to the left, hiding the vertical headers.

### ----Related Codes----

My tableivew is called **tableViewTransaction**, it uses a **model** to link to **data** in pandas' *dataframe* format.  Here is how I connected them together inside the `__init__` function of a *QMainWindow*.

```
    self.data = pd.read_csv('transactions.txt', sep='\t', header=None)
    self.data.columns = ["Name", "Price", "Action"]
    self.model = PandasModel(self.data)
    self.tableViewTransaction.setModel(self.model)
```

Here is my Model for the TableView

```
class PandasModel(QtCore.QAbstractTableModel): 
    def __init__(self, df = pd.DataFrame(), parent=None): 
        QtCore.QAbstractTableModel.__init__(self, parent=parent)
        self._df = df

    def headerData(self, section, orientation, role=QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole):
        if role != QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
            return QtCore.QVariant()

        if orientation == QtCore.Qt.Horizontal:
            try:
                return self._df.columns.tolist()[section]
            except (IndexError, ):
                return QtCore.QVariant()
        elif orientation == QtCore.Qt.Vertical:
            try:
                # return self.df.index.tolist()
                return self._df.index.tolist()[section]
            except (IndexError, ):
                return QtCore.QVariant()

    def data(self, index, role=QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole):
        if role != QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
            return QtCore.QVariant()

        if not index.isValid():
            return QtCore.QVariant()

        return QtCore.QVariant(str(self._df.ix[index.row(), index.column()]))

    def setData(self, index, value, role):
        row = self._df.index[index.row()]
        col = self._df.columns[index.column()]
        if hasattr(value, 'toPyObject'):
            # PyQt4 gets a QVariant
            value = value.toPyObject()
        else:
            # PySide gets an unicode
            dtype = self._df[col].dtype
            if dtype != object:
                value = None if value == '' else dtype.type(value)
        self._df.set_value(row, col, value)
        return True

    def rowCount(self, parent=QtCore.QModelIndex()): 
        return len(self._df.index)

    def columnCount(self, parent=QtCore.QModelIndex()): 
        return len(self._df.columns)

    def sort(self, column, order):
        colname = self._df.columns.tolist()[column]
        self.layoutChanged.emit()
        self._df.sort_values(colname, ascending= order == QtCore.Qt.AscendingOrder, inplace=True)
        self._df.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=True)
        self.layoutChanged.emit()
```

When the ***Record button*** is pressed, the following function is called:

```
    def recordTransaction(self):
        name = self.comboBoxStock.currentText()
        price = self.lineEditMoney.text()
        action = self.comboBoxAction.currentText()

        self.data.loc[len(self.data.index)] = [name, price, action]
        self.tableViewTransaction.model().layoutChanged.emit()
```

I know that name, price, action here is storing the correct information i.e. "stock1", "2", "Buy" in my above example.

### ----Full Code----

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rU66yLqlQu0bTdINkSWxJe2E_OdMtS0i/view?usp=sharing

How to use:
first unzip it, then use python3 to run StockSim.py.
On a mac, just run `python3 StockSim.py` when you have went to the *Stock Sim* directory using terminal.  Make sure you have python3 and pyqt5 installed first.

### ----------------------

All I want is that the TableView not shift to the left, any of your help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: In Linux with PyQt5 5.11.2 I do not see that problem. What is the version of PyQt5 that you have?

Comment: I have PyQt5 5.11.1 on mac